how to log failed SSH logins in a PAM module
I have been working on a pam module which logs logins for any SSH user     I have a simple piece of C code which logs the login to a log file
I cannot figure out how to record failed logins
I have read the documentation and still am unable to figure it out
any ideas on which functions i need to work with?
#include <security/pam_modules.h>
#include <security/pam_ext.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <time.h>

// Function to log the event
void log_event(const char *username, const char *event) {
    FILE *log_file = fopen("/var/log/pam_ssh_logins.log", "a");
    if (log_file) {
        time_t now = time(NULL);
        fprintf(log_file, "%s - %s: %s\n", ctime(&now), username, event);
        fclose(log_file);
    } else {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "Failed to open log file");
    }
}

// Open session function
PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_open_session(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {
    const char *username;
    if (pam_get_user(pamh, &username, NULL) == PAM_SUCCESS) {
        log_event(username, "Logged in via SSH");
    }
    return PAM_SUCCESS;
}

// Close session function
PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_close_session(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {
    const char *username;
    if (pam_get_user(pamh, &username, NULL) == PAM_SUCCESS) {
        log_event(username, "Logged out from SSH");
    }
    return PAM_SUCCESS;
}



PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_setcred(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {
    return PAM_IGNORE;
}

PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_acct_mgmt(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {
    return PAM_IGNORE;
}

I tried using the pam_sm_authenticate function but i cannot quite get it to work

You can write function pam_sm_authenticate for example and add your code log_event where return values.
PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_authenticate(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {
    const char * password=NULL;
    struct passwd *pwd;
    const char *user;
    int pam_err=0;
    /* identify user */
    pam_err = pam_get_user(pamh, &user, NULL);
    if (pam_err != PAM_SUCCESS)
    {
        log_event(...)
        return (pam_err);
    }
    if ((pwd = getpwnam(user)) == NULL)
    {
        log_event(...)
        return (PAM_USER_UNKNOWN);
    }
    /* note : if user is not defined password return will be "^H$^M^?INCORRECT^@" */
    pam_err  = pam_get_authtok(pamh, PAM_AUTHTOK, &password , NULL);
    if (pam_err!=PAM_SUCCESS)
    {
        log_event(...)
        return (pam_err);
    }

    /* here add personal auhtentication */
    pam_err = isAuthenticate((char *)user,(char *)password);
    if (pam_err != PAM_OK)
    {
        log_event(...)
        return (PAM_AUTH_ERR);
    }
    log_event(...)
    return (PAM_SUCCESS);
}

Very important step will be to configure the file /etc/pam.d/system-auth because you have to check the password input with the required parameter.
If I were doing such a task, I would choose another bullet:

monitor messages in a file /var/log/messages
rewrite the authorization module with the addition of its own logging. https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/master/libpam/pam_password.c (show function pam_syslog)

